# Populating HTML body background value from the database

Tags: asp.net, html

How would I go about populating a database value to my html body background ?
Simply put, the HTML code is something like:

```
<body background="<%=session("userLogo")%>">
```

**Update**
Clarification of my question: Where in the code-behind, should I make the database call to populate the session("userLogo") value ?

Comment: `<body background="session("userLogo")">` is malformed markup as there is no attribute userLogo (`background="session(" userLogo")"`) – be aware of doubled double quotes. Also, what should that background-value (`session…`) mean?

Comment: You can use a generic HTML control as described here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066031/dynamic-background-image-on-body-asp-net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this in your aspx:

```
body { background-image: url(<%= session("userLogo") %>); }
```

You can also put this in a css file (but then it has be an embedded resource and do remember to do `performSubstitution = true`)

Comment: Doesn't the HTML load before the Page_Load event?

Answer (score 0):

Use `<%= %>`

```
<body background="<%= /* Code to retrieve value */ %>">
```