# Trying to set background image, but div id name doesn't show up in code behind, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to set a background-image for a blog header in ASP web forms. I'm not sure what the best practice is, but the image is set dynamically, and I have a `<div>` element with the `id="blogHeaderImage"` and `runat="server"`. In the code-behind I'm trying to set the image with 
`blogHeaderImage.Attributes.Add("style", "display: none");`
but `blogHeaderImage` gives the error "The name "blogHeaderImage" does not exist in this context".

What am I missing here? Thank you in advanced.

---

I've tried the approved answers in:
[How do you modify style in the code behind file for divs in ASP.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657144/how-do-you-modify-style-in-the-code-behind-file-for-divs-in-asp-net)
and
[Find div tag from code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265103/find-div-tag-from-code-behind)

But this:

`<div id="blogHeaderImage" runat="server" class="blog-header-image cover" style='background-position: 30% 100%'>`

along with this:

`blogHeaderImage.Style.Add("background-image", "url(" + thisPage.HeaderImg + ")");`

Doesn't work (error message above).

---

I would like to use `thisPage.HeaderImg` (a url) as the background image.

Comment: this is duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066031/dynamic-background-image-on-body-asp-net.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `OnInit(EventArgs e)` event method to get image dynamic into body.
Please refer below link.

[Dynamic background-image on body (ASP.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066031/dynamic-background-image-on-body-asp-net)